# I need some assistance in Python

Tags: python-2.7

```
# -*- coding: cp1253 -*-
value=input("Καταχώρησε τιμή για το αρχικό ποσό:")
basic=value
prosf_bulk=0
prosfores=[]
names=[]
while prosf_bulk <=10 and value < basic*2.0:
    name=raw_input("Πώς ονομάζεστε?:")
    prosfora=input("Ποιά ειναι η προσφορά σου?")
    while prosfora <= value:
        print"Η τωρινή τιμή του αντικειμένου:",value,"ευρώ"
        prosfora=input("Δώσε μεγαλύτερη προσφορά:")
    value=prosfora
    prosf_bulk+=1
    prosfores.append(prosfora)
    names.append(name)
    print"H τωρινή αξία του αντικειμένου:",value,"ευρώ."
a=len(prosfores)
prosfores.pop(a-1)
names.pop(a-1)
second=0
for i in range a:
    if prosfores[i]>=second:
        second=prosfores[i]
        second_name=names[i]
final_prosf=[]
for i in range(2):
    print"Η τωρινή μέγιστη προσφορά",value,"euro"
    prosfora=input("Δώσε μία τελική προσφορά:")
    while prosfora < value:
        prosfora=input("Δώσε μεγαλύτερη ή ίση προσφορά:")
        print"Η τωρινή τιμή του αντικειμένου:",value,"ευρώ"
        final_prosf.append(prosfora)
if final_prosf[0]!=final_prosf[1]:
    if final_prosf[0]>final_prosf[1]:
        print"Ο/η",names[0],"θα αποκτήσει το προιόν με ποσοστιέα αύξηση από την αρχική τιμή:",(basic*100.0)/float(final_prosf[0]),"%"
    elif final_prosf[1]>final_prosf[0]:
        print"Ο/η",names[1],"θα αποκτήσει το προιόν με ποσοστιέα αύξηση από την αρχική τιμή:",(basic*100.0)/float(final_prosf[1]),"%"
else:
    print"Η δημοπρασία κρίνεται άκυρη λόγο ίσων προσφορών."
```

thats the code,but it shows that error:

```
line 23, 
    if prosfores[i]>=second:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried for quite some time to find the problem,but i can't resolve it. I would appreciate any help. I am begginer. Ignore the greek letters,the problem is on syntax or smthing. thanks

Comment: You are doing `for i in range(a):` where `a` is `len(prosfores)`. But after assigning `a` you are doing `prosfores.pop(a-1)` so now `a` is no longer the size of `prosfores` - it is bigger. Why not just do `for i in range(len(prosfores))`?

Answer (score 0):

missing ():

```
for i in range(a):
```

and also:

```
for i in range(a-1)
```

because you removed the last item: => prosfores.pop(a-1)

```
if len(final_prosf) == 2:
    if final_prosf[0] > final_prosf[1]:
        print...
    elif final_prosf[0] < final_prosf[1]:
        print...
    elif final_prosf[0] == final_prosf[1]
        print...
else:
    raise Exception("...")
```

Comment: i wrote it correctly but still i get the same error

Comment: modify the range to (a-1)

Comment: if final_prosf[0]!=final_prosf[1]:
IndexError: list index out of range- line 34

Comment: if len(final_prosf) >= 2: if final_prosf[0]!=final_prosf[1]: ...